# How and where to use "There be Dragons"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I've only known or seen "There be Dragons" as interchangeable with "Here be Dragons" as in the context of internet meme maps that make fun of countryside areas. Like **[this one](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-UqJzLvvcEHM/Tk3f8xii3bI/AAAAAAAADk8/yUCzbak-63w/s1600/masshole%2Bmap.jpg)**. However, In **[a different post on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/62296/21602)** I found an answer with "There be Dragons" in a context I couldn't quite figure out.  From the proficiency of the written answer I am assuming this usage of "There be Dragons" has a distinct meaning that isn't an anomaly specific to that particular English user.

> "These terms have comparative (darker, fairer) and superlative (darkest, fairest) forms and can be used of people of any complexion. So you could describe a white person with brown hair as being darker than a redhead.
>   So you could, if you had reason to, describe someone as simply a very dark African-American (though "African-American" is really not very common outside of America). Although it is worth noting that **there be dragons**. However, it is not necessarily politically incorrect or offensive at all and such terms can obviously be very useful if discussing racial politics or prejudice or whatever."

Comment: What's wrong with e.g. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/here_be_dragons? (Found by typing `define "There be Dragons"` into my favorite search engine.)

Comment: The wiktionary article forgot to say how they explain the subjunctive "be".

Answer (score 2):

"There be" is not current in modern English. The author is alluding to contexts in which quoting this phrase from old maps occurs.  It's a facetious or quaint way of saying "This is a contentious subject and some people may take offense. Proceed with caution."  When to use it? Whenever pirate talk is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, he uses **there** instead of **here** because he talks about a land outside of where he is so **here** would not fit in this particular context.

But the meaning is exactly the same.

Also for a more in-depth explanation of the expression you can check [here be dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons) on wikipedia or as @Nathan Tuggy suggested in the comments the [wikitionnary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/here_be_dragons)

Answer (score 0):

Medieval mapmakers used to draw dragons, sea serpents, and various other creatures in dangerous unexplored territory on maps. "Here there be dragons" is a phrase meant to be humorous referring to that, saying that this territory (usually metaphorical) is too dangerous for further exploration. "There be" is a conjugation that is no longer frequently used; it's used here as a reference to the era of the Dark Ages because it sounds old. The phrase is also occasionally used jokingly in programming, usually right before a section of particularly difficult or complicated code.